# Spring Boot Rest Security Basic Auth Password Encoder does not encrypt password on login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The problem is, BCryptPasswordEncoder is not encrypt the password on login process therefore login fails, let's say password is 123 and stored in db as hashed, when the post the password 123 returns invalid_grants, but when the hashed password is sent from client, returns the access token. It is also ok when the password when password encoder is commented.

> App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }



    @Autowired
    public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, final UserRepository userRepository, UserService userService) throws Exception {
        if(userRepository.count() == 0) {

            User user = new User();
            Role role = new Role();
            role.setName("SA");
            user.setEmail("test");
            user.setPassword("123");
            user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(role));
            user.setBlocked(false);
            user.setEnable(true);
            userService.save(user);
        }
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(email -> {
            return userService.loadUserByUsername(email);
        });
    }
}
```

> WebSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String SIGNING_KEY = "kKSMJ92Mknk38njs9HJ8KNALiuc938FH";
    static final int ENCODING_STRENGTH = 256;
    static final String SECURITY_REALM = "Task Manager";


    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired 
    private DataSource dataSource;




    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth
         .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
         .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
         .and()
         .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
         .jdbcAuthentication()
         .dataSource(dataSource);
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/sign-up", "/sign-in", "/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .realmName(SECURITY_REALM)
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable();
    }



    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;


}
```

> UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired 
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));;
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = this.userRepository.findUserByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new CustomUserDetails(user);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be here. Remove the lines that are commented out.

```
@Autowired
public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, final UserRepository userRepository, UserService userService) throws Exception {
    if(userRepository.count() == 0) {

        User user = new User();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setName("SA");
        user.setEmail("test");
        user.setPassword("123");
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(role));
        user.setBlocked(false);
        user.setEnable(true);
        userService.save(user);
    }
   // authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(email -> {
   //     return userService.loadUserByUsername(email);
   // });
}
```

You are overriding all the multiple configurations that you have done in your configuration classes, and as a result the password encoder is never applied to your `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.